# RecursiveDirectoryIterator constructor returns empty object

Tags: php

I have a problem with the following line:

```
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
```

This code returns an empty object even though the $directory folder contains at least one file. I also double checked the value of $directory and it's the right path

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use a foreach, because print_f will output empty object even if the object is not empty.
You can check this out like that:

```
foreach ($iterator as $name => $file) {
    echo $file->getRealPath().'<br>';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
$iterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
     new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path),
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
```

It should get you a file list or throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I tried the code and put a print_f after that and all I get is RecursiveIteratorIterator Object ( )

Comment: The entire code is:
 
$iterator = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($directory);
$iterator->setFlags(RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
$filter = new MyRecursiveFilterIterator($iterator);
$all_files  = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($filter,RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
And it shows this error: Fatal error: Call to undefined method RecursiveDirectoryIterator::setFlags()